# can not assign a 2-d array to struct in c

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a snake game. I have a structure which contains data of the snake, such as position of snake length etc. This is the `snake.h` file:

```c
#ifndef SNAKE_HEAEDER
#define SNAKE_HEAEDER 

#include "direction.h"
#include <string.h>

struct Snake {

        int length;
        int* pos[2];
        int first_pos[2];
        int last_pos[2];
        int direction;

};

void set_snake(struct Snake *snake, int length_, int pos_[][2], int direction_){

        snake->length    = length_              ;
        memcpy(snake->pos, pos_, length_)       ;
        printf("hello\n");
        memcpy(snake->first_pos, pos_[length_-1],1)  ;
        memcpy(snake->last_pos, pos_[0],1)      ;
        snake->direction = direction_           ;
}
```

and in the `main.c` :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "snake.h"


int main(){

        struct Snake *snake;
        int pos[2][2] = {{1,2}};
        set_snake(snake,1,pos,UP);
        return 0;
}
```

and in `direction.h`:

```c
#ifndef DIRECTIONS_HEADER
#define DIRECTIONS_HEADER

#define UP    0 
#define DOWN  1
#define RIGHT 2
#define LEFT  3

#define CURRENT_DIRECTION(x) (x.direction)

#endif
```

The problem is that it can not do `memcpy` in `set_snake`. The `hello` will never be shown. I get segmentation fault. The thing I need is a 2 dimensional array which contains address of the pixel which snake is in, and the length is the number of pixels the snake would occupy.

I hope if there is lack of detail, let me know it.

Comment: Why don't you allocate memory like this: `struct Snake *snake = malloc(sizeof *snake);`

Comment: ...Or just don't make it a pointer: `struct Snake snake;`

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang what's  benefit of that?

Comment: In `memcpy()` calls you are not taking into account the size of each element. An `int` is larger then 1 byte.

Comment: Don't put function definitions in a header file.  Header files should only contain declarations.

Answer (score 0):

As [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) pointed out in the comments, you are not taking the size of each element into account.

This function should allocate memory correctly:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Snake *set_snake(int length_, int pos_[][2], int direction_)
{
    struct Snake *snake = malloc(sizeof *snake + sizeof(int[length_][2]));

    snake->length = length_;
    memcpy(snake->pos, pos_, sizeof(int[length_][2]));
    memcpy(snake->first_pos, pos_[length_-1], sizeof(int[2]));
    memcpy(snake->last_pos, pos_[0], sizeof(int[2]));
    snake->direction = direction_;

    return snake;
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
struct Snake *snake;
snake = set_snake(1, pos, UP);
```

By the way, when I wrote a Snake game in C, I stored the x- and y-coordinate of each element in a linked list, which is very easy to manipulate. If you are interested, you can have a look at [my implementation](https://gitlab.com/andy-sb/ssnk).

Comment: The function doesn't return anything, is it ok?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi You are right, returning `snake` is important. I have now updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I think you're assigning `length_` to `snake->pos` which does not work.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi Thats because I copied your code incorrectly. I have now updated my answer again. Does it work otherwise? If yes, please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I got this error `snake.h:37:16: error: assignment to expression with array type
   37 |     snake->pos = pos_;
`

Comment: no it give me `snake.h:13:6: error: flexible array member not at end of struct
   13 |  int pos[][2];
`

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi Okay now it should finally work! Let me know if it does.